# Is it possible to use pre Authenticated Security Firewalls in Silex?

Tags: symfony, silex

I have tried to use Symfony's pre Authenticated Security Firewalls in Silex, but I get this error "The "remote_user" authentication entry is not registered".

Do anyone know if this is possible with Silex?

I would like use Apache's basic auth and load roles from DB.

silex/silex, v1.3.4
symfony/security, v2.7.4

This is my config:

```
$app->register(
    new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), [
        'security.firewalls' => [
            'secured_area' => [
                'pattern' => '^/',
                'remote_user' => [
                    'users' => $app->share(
                        function () use ($app) {
                            return new UserProvider($app['db']);
                        }
                    ),
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

Comment: Can you share some code and config used?

Comment: @mTorres: Updated with config.

Comment: You are missing an authentication method: you didn't tell the security system which method should be using to authenticate your users: form login, HTTP Auth, x509 certificates, etc. Oh, and you didn't tell us either, which authenticated method are you using?

Comment: @mTorres:  I thought I could let Apache do the authentication and just send the remote_user variable to Silex/Symfony. I guess I have misunderstood. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/pre_authenticated.html

Comment: My Bad, you could theoretically do that (as I understand the docs, I've never used this option), I've read ```users``` instead of *remote_user* -_-' I can tell that your config is missing the *provider key* under your ```remote_user``` entry, may be you can pull this thread and see where you arrive.